# Modifying "this" inside Angular controller using bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular new router components and also js.
I have multiple controllers as the one bellow.

What I'm trying to do is to apply a function to this for all controllers, do I don't have to do it in each one.

```
function HomeController (authService, factoryClient) {
    console.log ('this is home controller');
    this = doCommonController.bind(this); //generates an error
    //here this should contain currentUser, authService, logout and testVar
    console.log(this);
}
```

and the function is:

```
var doCommonController = function (authService, currentUser) {
    this.testVar = 'value';
    this.authService = authService;
    this.currentUser =  currentUser;
    this.logout = this.authService.logout;
}
```

Also, how do I pass **authService** and **factoryClient** from controller to be available in doCommonController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use .call() not .bind(), also don't assign any value to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) that is invalid

```
function HomeController(authService, factoryClient) {
    console.log('this is home controller');
    var currentUser;
    doCommonController.call(this, authService, currentUser); //generates an error
    //here this should contain currentUser, authService, logout and testVar
    console.log(this);
}
```